# BCM43142 wifi adapter drops connection on windows 10

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

The problem started when I upgraded my new (3 days) windows 8.1 laptop to win10. Wifi networking worked nicely on 8.1, but after the upgrade, the wifi adapter is very slow and randomly reports 100% signal reception and then drops connections. It then may return to a connected (but slow) state for 2 minutes before dropping again or connecting in `limited` connection. It only does this on my home network. updating drivers did noting.
I discovered with a little bit of research that the `BCM43142` is known for the above described behaviour on systems as old as windows vista, but I did found any solutions for that problem.

Edit: as I write this, I didn't experience any disconnections of any sort, nor extreme slowness for about 2 hours straignt.

Comment: An alternative may be [HomePlug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HomePlug)  (Ethernet over electrical wires) possibly faster as well.  Supports gigabit class speeds.  i.e. plug jack into electrical by router, connect with ethernet. then plug second jack in power jack where notebook is wanted and connect ethernet to notebook.

Comment: @StackAbstraction I had already thought about it to get high-speed far from the router without running ethernet all over the walls, but my concern is more about other networks (like if it didn't work at school, I'd be in serious trouble, as there is no ethernet plugs in classrooms)

Comment: I have a similar issue. Pls see http://superuser.com/questions/1023244/windows-10-wifi-connection-drops-throughput-issue

Comment: @Kshitij not the same problem. Mine involved the adapter reporting absolute 100% signal seconds before dropping, regardless of the distance between the adapter and the router.  In your case it seems to be a power-save mode problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like my problem solved itself 15 minutes after a reboot caused by an update. The update was supposed to solve "security problems" so it is unclear if the update did something to this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do a little bit of command-line here, as per my knowledge, it is good hit if you succeed it. i ran into a website which is talking about wifi issue cause of windows 10 upgrade.

maybe it will help, check this out: http://www.redmondpie.com/fix-no-wi-fi-available-after-windows-10-upgrade-issue-heres-how/

Comment: This article talks about users not being able to see network. I was able to see and connect to networks, but not get a stable connection on some networks.

Comment: not stable network can be in few factors, some interference caused by too many routers around the neighbor which near enough that your laptop can detect or indeed software issues after upgrading.did you try to reset your wifi instead? and to get it refreshed? the point is, i have the same problem with my home network which is not far away from the position i am accessing it. i reset it and now it works fine. I mean if it is trule software issue regarding your wifi adapter, it should be totally unreadable to the available network.

Comment: My home network works well with all my other devices